# Convert nonlinear regression equation to a linear regression equation

Tags: statistics, regression

The question is:

> Show how the nonlinear regression equation $y=aX^B$ can be converted to a linear regression equation solvable by the method of least squares.

I found how to take $Y=Ae^{bX}u$ to a linear equation $y=a+bX+v$, where $y=\ln(Y)$, $a=\ln(A)$ and $v=\ln(u)$.

However, I feel like there is a key difference between that example and my equation. The base of the exponential equation is $e$ in their example and $X$ in mine. The base being $e$ in their example is what allows then to simplify $\ln(e^{bX})=bX$, right? So I'm not sure what to do with my equation. I'm assuming the answer is not as simple as $y=a+B \ln(X)$. Because this is still not linear.

Any help explaining this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If $y = aX^B$ then $\log y = (\log a) + B\log X$.  The intercept is $\log a$ and the slope is $B$; the independent and dependent variables are $\log X$ and $\log y$.  The base of the logarithms can be any positive number except $1$.

Comment: And you can solve "log(y) = log(a)+Blog(X) by the method of least squares? This is the linear equation that they are looking for?

Comment: It can be done if you have data.  Whether it's appropriate depends on the context.  It's often appropriate when you see a graph that looks like the one on the second page of this document: http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/courses/bio621/misc/Chocolate%20consumption%20cognitive%20function%20and%20nobel%20laurates%20(NEJM).pdf

Comment: OK, that graph seems to jive with what we are working on in class. Thanks for the explanation.